# FormView Image control

Tags: asp.net, repeater, formview

Hi i am currently working in Asp.net using C# language.

Please any one tell me how to show picture that are stored server table(data type image) in asp:image control.
thanks.

Comment: You question is unclear. Are you asking how to use the `asp:Image` control?

Comment: @Blachshma  Yes that image control should display picture stored in server table(DataType Image).Sorry for delay

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to save the image in some folder on your website, and use a URL to link to that image. Since this is going to be done for every request, I'm guessing you can understand this is ***not*** a best practice.

The correct way to do this is save all images in a single directory on your website, and in the DB only store the URL for that image.